# Centering a fixed height/width dialog on screen of variable window size

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari, vertical-alignment

I am attempting to center a dialog that has fixed height and width (750x360) on the screen using jquery mobile and CSS3 (without javascript calculations). This will be run on IPad mobile safari and so far I have not found a version of calc() that works on that browser.

I am currently centering by calculating margin-top using javascript. Params being the variable height of the window and fixed height of the dialog. However I need to remove this from my implementation to meet standards, and only use CSS/jquery methods if possible.

Is there a way to do this?

I am importing both jquery UI and jquery mobile libraries, so I have access to all their methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example on how to center a `div` vertically and horizontally:

```
#center {
   background-color: red;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-top: -50px; /* half the height */
   margin-left: -50px; /* half the width */        
}​
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aecrf/)

To position an element you use `position:absolute` this way you can specify where the element should be without having to worry about other elements. To center the element we want to position it on `50%` on the container size. But if we stop there the element top left corner will be centered. Therefore we have to add the `margin`'s.

Hope this can help you in the right direction.

Comment: The problem with this is that i am attempting to center a jquery mobile Dialog of fixed dimensions. This dialog has menus and text boxes on it. My teammate tried this solution a while ago but it caused any menus/dropdowns opened in the dialog to be shoved right and down, the same distance that the dialog was moved. This would be fine if jquery used the browser origin for pixel distance calculation, but it doesnt, it uses the origin of the dialog, which is now 200+ pixels right and down of where jquery thinks it is.

Comment: Is it a standard jQuery ui dialog? Then it should be centered by default if you haven't passed something else([documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-position)). If you could it would be nice if you added some example code (at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)) to play around with.